# Update the content in the block without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

There index.html page

There is a block , such as class content , in which a lot of different content blocks .

There is also a navigation menu , with lots of links , and it is necessary that when you click on one of the menu links updated content in the block with the content class , then when you click on a different menu link old content disappeared and appeared new .

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery pjax. [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) is a jQuery plugin that uses ajax and pushState to deliver a fast browsing experience with real permalinks, page titles, and a working back button.